# Codebehind and inline on same page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, inline, code-behind

In ASP.NET, is it possible to use both code behind and inline on the same page? I want to add some inline code that's related to the UI of the page, the reason to make it inline is to make it easy to modify as it outputs some HTML which is why I don't want to add it in the code behind, is this possible in ASP.NET?

Edit: I'm sorry, obviously my question wasn't very clear, what I meant is using a script block with runat="server", this is what I meant by inline code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use inline code just like in classic asp. You can use 'this' or 'me' to get to the code behind fields, methods, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work, make sure the code behind class is declared as a partial class, which is the default these days anyway. Don't think it would work in 1 or 1.1